What can be the the max current for this terminal?
Im looking for a panel mount screw or push terminal which can handle upto 5A DC. I came across this one. I could not find any besides it.
It is written Rated load : AC50V 3A
In my case the wire will pass max 5A DC current at coming from a 12V power supply.
Is the max current independent of voltage here still 3A ot?

Current and voltage limits need to be respected simultaneously and independently. You cannot use it with a 5A load, nor do you have any assurance that it is rated for DC (more of a problem with switches).
